# How to write a self referencing Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a Django model "`Inspection`" which has:

```
InspectionID (PK)
PartID
SiteID
Date
Comment
Report
Signiture
```

I want to be able to have a one to many relationship between the inspection ID and date. So one ID can have inspections at many dates. How would I do this? I currently have the following:

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
    InspectionID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    PartID = models.ForeignKey('Part', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SiteID = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Report = models.FileField(upload_to='docs', null=True, blank=True)
    Signiture = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I thought about using `models.ForeignKey` but I really don't know how to implement that properly in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to have a one to many relationship between the inspection ID and date.

You create an extra model, like:

```
class InspectionDate(models.Model):
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(
        Inspection,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='inspectiondates'
    )
    date = models.DateField()
```

You thus can create `InspectionDate`s for a given `Inspection`.

Or if you want to add extra data, it might be better to define an `InspectionGroup` model:

```
class InspectionGroup(models.Model):
    pass

class Inspection(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_column='InspectionId')
    inspectiongroup = models.ForeignKey(InspectionGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='InspectionGroupId')
    part = models.ForeignKey('Part', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='PartId')
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='SiteId')
    date = models.DateField(db_column='Date')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_column='CommentId')
    report = models.FileField(upload_to='docs', null=True, blank=True, db_column='ReportId')
    signiture = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_column='Signature')
```

> **Note**: the name of attributes are normally written in [*`snake_case`* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), not in <s>*`PerlCase`*</s> or <s>*`camelCase`*</s>.

Comment: Ah ok. So there's no way I can do this within one model? If I wanted to have the comment/report/signature included with each inspection date would this need to be grouped with inspection date too rather than with Inspection?

Comment: @Cm1602: but then would you make an `InspectionGroup`, and put `Inspection`s under that. By refering to another `Inspection`, you create a complicated structure. For example say there are three related inspections `A`, `B` and `C`. Then how do you relate those, link `B` to `A`, and `C` to `B`, or both to `A`?

Comment: I can kinda see why having two models would be helpful here then... I'd like to have the 'InspectionID' be the attribute to link them together. ID remains constant with 'SiteID' and 'PartID'. But there will be a comment/report/signature for every date that the item is inspected.

Comment: @Cm1602: but since `InspectionID` is a primary key, you can not use the same id on multiple records. A primary key should be *unique*. Normally that is enforced by the database.

Comment: So I'd need a way in that case of only having multiple instances of the inspection content, under the inspection banner. So one instance of inspection containing the other two ID's, with multiple 'Content' objects with a foreign key 'date'. Would something like this work?

Comment: @Cm1602: a *relational database* is often not good with arrays, and it is normally not advisable to use these. A "cascading database", linke MongoDB is. Some databases like PostgreSQL, have a JSON field, but even then it is often better to avoid that. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation

Answer (score 0):

you may store '**self Foriegnkey**' as

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
    InspectionID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    PartID = models.ForeignKey('Part', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SiteID = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Report = models.FileField(upload_to='docs', null=True, blank=True)
    Signiture = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    inspection_id = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Does this not reference a whole Inspection object though? Which means that InspectionID is no longer unique as it is repeated multiple times. This would only allow me to link inspections with different ID's, which I don't want to do.